# Microsoft Word 2016: Continue the current column in the same page

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a table with two columns, when it grows, it continues to the next page:

```
+------------+---------+
|    SN      | Name    |
+------------+---------+
| 1          | Foo     |
| 2          | Bar     |
| ...        | ...     |
| N          | thud    |
+------------+---------+
```

How can I make it continue on the same page (wraps)? something like this

```
+------------+---------+------------+---------+
|    SN      | Name    | SN         | Name    |
+------------+---------+------------+---------+
| 1          | Foo     | 26         | Qux     |
| 2          | Bar     | ...        | ...     |
| ...        | ...     | N          | Thud    |
| 25         | Baz     |+------------+--------+
+------------+---------+
```

I tried `Layout` -> `Columns` --> `Two`. But the header doesn't repeat.
Also, I don't want to create a table with two seperate columns because I need to sort it.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, but you have to fake the repeating header, so it's only really workable if you never change your column layout.

It uses linked text boxes.

Insert three text boxes. (NB, this will probably happen automatically, but make sure they are all anchored to the same paragraph. The first one will hold the first part of the table. The second one will hold a copy of the header row The third will hold the second part of the table. Like this, but taller:

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|                         |                         |
|                         +-------------------------+
|                         |                         |
|                         |                         |
|                         |                         |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Select each text box and

- set the outline to "No Outline"
- right-click and select Format Shape to bring up the Format Shape pane. In there, click *Text Options* then the *Layout and Properties* icon and set all the internal margins to 0.

Select the first text box, then click the *Shape Format* ribbon tab, *Text* group, *Create Link* option. Now click in the 3rd text box.

Insert your table in the first text box. It should flow into the 3rd text box automatically. But as with a "snaking columns" layout, the headers are not repeated at the top of the second box.

So you have to copy and paste the header row(s) into the 2nd box. You may need to do a bit of box rearrangement to get the header row to look as if it is actually part of the table below.